# Generic void* stating that the request for member 'word' is not a structure or union

Tags: c, struct, void-pointers

I am new to the void pointer in C. Unfortunately, when I try to call a variable within a structure, it throws me the error:

```
[Error] request for member 'word' in something not a structure or union
```

I was under the impression all that was necessary to do was create a void* var, which could then be used to reference any data, or be set to any value

```
    #include <stdlib.h>

struct node{
    void* listHeader; 
    struct node *next; 
}; 

struct otherNode {
   /*The word it stores*/ 
   char* word; 

};

void Method(struct node *header);

int main(){
     struct node *header = malloc(sizeof(struct node)); 
     Method(header); 
     return 0; 
}
void Method(struct node *header){
    (struct otherNode)(header->listHeader).word = "ties";
    
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!! Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 2):

Two problems with this line:

> (struct otherNode)(header->listHeader).word = "ties";

1. Operator predecence. `.` has priority over casting.
2. You're trying to cast (void*) to (struct otherNode). You can't really do that, you could cast it to pointer to that struct, which would look like:

```
((struct otherNode*)header->listHeader)->word = "ties";
```

This will make your code compile, but it will not run successfully, because you have not set `header->listHeader` to point anywhere (`header->listHeader = malloc(sizeof(struct otherNode));` ?), so you're writing to memory area where you shouldn't.

---

Resources:

https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence